# xcodebuild: error: Unknown build action

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, xcodebuild

When I'm try to build from the command line:

```
xcodebuild -target -project myApp.xcodeproj -scheme myApp -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release archive -archivePath $PWD/build/DDCiOSClient.xcarchive
```

I'm getting this error:

```
User defaults from command line:
    IDEArchivePathOverride = /depot/myApp/myApp.xcarchive

Build settings from command line:
    SDKROOT = iphoneos9.3

xcodebuild: error: Unknown build action 'myApp.xcodeproj'.
```

Any of you knows why of this error?

Comment: Did you `cd` to your project's directory?

Answer (score 5):

The phrase `-target -project` is meaningless. You need to supply a target after the `-target` argument name.

Also, the action `archive` needs to come last.

Comment: Also, you can mention "-alltargets" instead if you donot wish to specify any targets and point to all available targets.